# I can not get data from JSON file to display it in view, I am working with smart filter bar

Tags: sapui5

when I click on Start (Go) in smart filter bar I get no data. It should a table with my data in `model.json` file appears. When I tried to use `attachRequestCompleted` method, I got message as success.

Someone can help please?

```js
"ProductCollection": [{
        "ProductId": "12391099",
        "Name": "BMW20",
        "Category": "EA",
        "SupplierName": "BMW",
        "Status": "In Stock",
        "Quantity": "99",
        "DateOfProduction": "2017-03-26",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": "9700",
        "Description": "Durchstöbern Sie 11.679 bmw Stock-Fotografie und Bilder. Oder starten Sie eine neue Suche, um noch mehr Stock-Fotografie und Bilder zu entdecke",
        "ProductPicUrl": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3689532/pexels-photo-3689532.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
        "SupplierWebsite": "https://www.bmw.com/de/index.html",
        "Street": "Berlinerstraße",
        "HouseNumber": "29",
        "ZIPCode": "45873",
        "City": "Siegen"
    .....
    .....
```

```css
<mvc:View controllerName="com.volkswagen.ifdb.cc.sopraempSmartTable.controller.View1" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:smartfilterbar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar"
    xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <smartfilterbar:SmartFilterBar id="idSmartFilterBar" entitySet="{/ProductCollection}">
                        
                        
                    </smartfilterbar:SmartFilterBar>
    
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

```html
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"

], function(Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("com.volkswagen.ifdb.cc.sopraempSmartTable.controller.View1", {

        onInit: function() {

            this.oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            this.oModel.loadData("model.json");
            this.getView().setModel(this.oModel);
        }

    });
});
```